# Transforming a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to transform a pandas dataframe into a new format.

I had two dataframes that I merged. The new dataframe contains duplicate entries and I want to transform it so that each of these duplicate entries is in a single row with extra columns that contain data of this duplication. I tried to use .pivot, .pivot_table, .melt, .unstack, but was unsuccessful to achieve what I want.

Assuming that I have dataframe d1:

```py
d1 = pd.DataFrame({"Wall ID": ["E12", "E12", "E12", "C35", "C35", "C35"],
                  "Length": [15, 15, 15, 21, 21, 21],
                  "Station": ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
                  "Time": [20, 14, 26, 29, 14, 12]})
d1
```

[image]

I want to change it to dataframe d2:

```py
d2 = pd.DataFrame({"Wall ID": ["E12", "C35"],
                  "Length": [15, 21],
                  "A1": [20, 29],
                  "A2": [14, 14],
                  "A3": [26, 12]})
d2
```

[image]

Note that "Length" is always the same for the same "Wall ID".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have performance you can use groupby:

Groupby is double faster than pivot table.

## setup

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Wall ID": ["E12", "E12", "E12", "C35", "C35", "C35"],
                  "Length": [15, 15, 15, 21, 21, 21],
                  "Station": ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
                  "Time": [20, 14, 26, 29, 14, 12]})

df
  Wall ID  Length Station  Time
0     E12      15      A1    20
1     E12      15      A2    14
2     E12      15      A3    26
3     C35      21      A1    29
4     C35      21      A2    14
5     C35      21      A3    12
```

## using pivot table

```py
%%timeit
df.pivot_table("Time", ["Wall ID","Length"], "Station").reset_index()
7.83 ms ± 503 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

## using groupby

```py
%%timeit

(df.groupby(["Wall ID", "Station","Length"]) # These are the indices we want
.agg({"Time": 'first'}) # We want to aggregatge Time, e.g. 'mean'
.unstack(level="Station") # Move Station to column section
.droplevel(0,axis=1) # Remove outermost multi-index of agg col 'Time'
.reset_index() # completely remove multi-index and make simple table
)
3.84 ms ± 300 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

## output

```
Station Wall ID  Length  A1  A2  A3
0           C35      21  29  14  12
1           E12      15  20  14  26
```

Comment: Thanks. Using `.pivot_table` seems easier but less flexible. However, my actual dataset is much complicated than this example. One thing I have not mentioned is that "Time" is actually a datatime object, not an integer. In this case, the aggregation won't work. is there a way to make it work ?? Moreover, other data fields exist (not just 'Length' ...) In concept, I would have to make them all as indexes, right?

Comment: @O.Mohsen 1. if your time column is string, you can make it integer using `df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype(int)`  or you may need to do some string manipulation,   such as df['mytime'] = df['Time'].str.slice(0,4) .astype(int) this will take first four numbers and make integer. Or, you can make it datetime column and then extract year, week or anything from that. 

2. If you need more indices, just add them to groupby index part. 

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for you input. Although it does not precisely solve my problem, but it gives me a better alternative way to solve it. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to know I was of help, If you have further question, do not hesitate to post new question. This whole platform is for learning in collaboration.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pivot_table`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Wall ID": ["E12", "E12", "E12", "C35", "C35", "C35"],
                  "Length": [15, 15, 15, 21, 21, 21],
                  "Station": ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
                  "Time": [20, 14, 26, 29, 14, 12]})

new_df = df.pivot_table("Time", ["Wall ID","Length"], "Station").reset_index()

print (new_df)

#
Station Wall ID  Length  A1  A2  A3
0           C35      21  29  14  12
1           E12      15  20  14  26
```